# php for loop with array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

PART 1: I need to create a loop for a set of array variables

```
for ($cnt=1; $cnt<=$qty; $cnt++) {
      $firstvar.$cnt['Code'] = '02';
      $secondvar.$cnt['Type'] = $somevar;
      $thirdvar.$cnt['Code'] = 'IN';
   }
```

// with a result of

```
      $firstvar1['Code'] = '02';
      $secondvar1['Type'] = $somevar;
      $thirdvar1['Code'] = 'IN';

      $firstvar2['Code'] = '02';
      $secondvar2['Type'] = $somevar;
      $thirdvar2['Code'] = 'IN';  

//etc.
```

However, the parsing of the $cnt variable seems to be conflicting with the array.

PART 2: I then need to create an array of variables like so:

```
  $lastvar['Thing'] = array( $thirdvar1, $thirdvar2, ... $thirdvar.$qty );
```

Here, creating a simple string using a for loop and placing it in the array doesn't work.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PART 1: `$firstvar.$cnt['Code']` should be `${"firstvar$cnt"}['Code']` (or `${'firstvar'.$cnt}['Code']`).

PART 2:

```
for ($cnt=1; $cnt<=$qty; $cnt++) {
    $lastvar['Thing'][] = ${'thirdvar'.$qty};
}
```

PART 3: (mine!)
Put everything in the same loop:

```
for ($cnt=1; $cnt<=$qty; $cnt++) {
  ${'firstvar'.$cnt}['Code']  = 02;
  ${'secondvar'.$cnt}['Type'] = $somevar;
  ${'thirdvar'.$cnt}['Code']  = 'IN';
  $lastvar['Thing'][]         = ${thirdvar$qty};
```

}

Keep in mind that this code would be cleaner if you use arrays instead of variables names concatenation.

Comment: This worked for me. I put it all in the same loop per your suggestion. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Thanks, Sammy! That was my first question here. Thanks to you and all who share their knowledge here. This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly do everything?

```
foreach ($cnt as $c) {
    $firstvar[$c['Code']] = 02;
    $secondvar[$c['Type']] = $somevar;
    $lastvar['Thing'][] = 'IN';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$somevar = "testValue";
$qty = 5;
$lastvar['Thing'] = array();
for($cnt=1; $cnt<=$qty; $cnt++) 
{
    ${"firstvar$cnt"} = array('Code' => '02', 'Type' => $someVar, "Code" => "IN");
    $lastvar['Thing'][] = ${"firstvar$cnt"};
}

var_dump($lastvar);
```

should work.